# Creating a code to double the user's input (bet) after each hole

Tags: python

```
bet = int(input('Enter your bet: ')) ##takes bet from user

for i in range (0,18): ##the range is for the number of holes being
                       ##played 
    bet *=2 ##double the bet amount for each hole
    print("hole", i, "$", bet) ## prints the wager for each hole
```

This is the output I get from this code, but the 1st hole should start at 10, then double from the 2nd hole onwards.

```
Enter your bet: 10
hole 1 $ 20
hole 2 $ 40
hole 3 $ 80
hole 4 $ 160
hole 5 $ 320
hole 6 $ 640
hole 7 $ 1280
hole 8 $ 2560
hole 9 $ 5120
hole 10 $ 10240
hole 11 $ 20480
hole 12 $ 40960
hole 13 $ 81920
hole 14 $ 163840
hole 15 $ 327680
hole 16 $ 655360
hole 17 $ 1310720
```

Comment: You want to double the value after you printed it. So why do you double the value before?

Comment: That is not the output from this code

Answer (score 1):

Simply print the value *before* doubling:

```
bet = int(input('Enter your bet: ')) ##takes bet from user

for i in range (1 ,19): ##the range is for the number of holes being played 
    print("hole", i, "$", bet) ## prints the wager for each hole
    bet *= 2 ##double the bet amount for each hole
```

Comment: And you might want to use `range(1, 19)`.

Answer (score 0):

So start with smaller number by dividing by 2 the start number

```
bet = int(input('Enter your bet: ')) / 2 ##takes bet from user

for i in range (0,18): ##the range is for the number of holes being
                       ##played
    bet *=2 ##double the bet amount for each hole
    print("hole", i, "$", bet) ## prints the wager for each hole
```

output:

```
Enter your bet: 10
hole 0 $ 10.0
hole 1 $ 20.0
...
hole 17 $ 1310720.0
```

Comment: Why add another operation? Why not just switch between the `print` and the multiplication?

Comment: Fixing bad logic in the code by manipulating the input parameters is not the way to go.

Comment: Well, that depends on what he needs. If  start 10 it go up to 2621440 but if start with 5 it go to 1310720. I thought that the first hole just don't count

Comment: @Matthias what would you suggest?